# EnumChildWindow and receiving a duplicate HWND

Tags: winapi

I am enumerating through the children of a given window with the help of `EnumChildWindow`. I want to store the received window handles (via `EnumChildProc`) in a collection. Is it guaranteed that the received handles are unique? According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494(VS.85).aspx) it sounds like they are unique during the enumeration but I am not sure if I understand it correctly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they're unique during the enumeration. You get a shapshot.